# Get the Patients Info from two Collections in MongoDB 3.6

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here are the two collections named Patients and Hospitals, I need to get the PatientId's data which is in Hospital Collections stored under patientsId's in string data format,  and  _id is stored as ObjectId below are the details:

```
**Hospital Collection :**
  {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c04b943ff491824b806686a"),
            "email" : "ayoub.khial@gmail.com",
            "password" : "$2a$10$4Wt5Rn6udxREdXCIt3hGb.sKhKUKOlyiYKmLTjYG3SqEPKFSw9phq",
"PatientDetails" : {
                "WeekJoined" : "Monday", 
                "description" : "I",
            "PatientIds" : [
                    "5a0c6797fd3eb67969316ce2",
                    "5c07ada8ff49183284e509d1",
                    "5c07acc1ff49183284e509d0"
            ]
} }

**Patient Collection :**

    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5a0c6797fd3eb67969316ce2"),
            "picture" : "http://placehold.it/150x150",
            "name" : "Genmom",
            "email" : "leilaware@genmom.com",
            "city" : "Rabat",
            "location" : {
                    "type" : "Point",
                    "coordinates" : [
                            -6.79387,
                            33.83957
                    ]
            }
    }
View Code :

 {
    "$lookup" : {
        "from" : "Patient",
        "localField" : "Hospital.PatientsDetails.PatientIds",
        "foreignField" : "_id",
        "as" : "PatientDetails"
    }
}
```

How can i handle data type conversion in Lookup in MongoDB 3.6

Comment: have you tried this `db.Hospital.aggregate([
   {
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "patient",
         localField: "PatientIds",
         foreignField: "_id",
         as: "PatientDetails"
       }
  }
])`

Comment: Yes that's the one i tried

Comment: I didn't see that `Patientids` was inside `PatientDetails` object

Answer (score 0):

local field should be  `PatientDetails.PatientIds`

If your `PatientIds` are as ObjectIds i.e

```
"PatientIds" : [
  ObjectId("5a0c6797fd3eb67969316ce2"),
  ObjectId("5c07ada8ff49183284e509d1"),
  ObjectId("5c07acc1ff49183284e509d0")
];
```

try this

```sh
>>>db.hospitals.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "patients",
      localField: "PatientDetails.PatientIds",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "PatientDetails"
    }
  }
]);
```

If your `PatientIds` are Strings try this

```sh
>>>db.hospitals.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "patients",
      let: { patientIds: "$PatientDetails.PatientIds" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: { $expr: { $in: [{ $toString: "$_id" }, "$$patientIds"] } }
        }
      ],
      as: "PatientDetails"
    }
  }
]);
```

Comment: I tried second one, it didn't work, BTW i'm using MongoDB 3.6 version

Comment: @uttamrao There is no `toString` (or `$convert`) operator in MongoDB version 3.6. It is only available in later version 4.0.

Comment: How can i handle above situation above now in MongoDB 3.6? @prasad_

Comment: Offhand, I can think of couple of things (but, you may want to do some research on Google). (1) Change your database to a newer version, _or_ (2) Convert the data (either have the `PatientIds` get changed to `ObjectId` types _or_ have a new field in the `Patient` document with the `_id`'s string value (can call the field as `_idStr`).

Comment: @prasad_ We dont have an option to go to newer version or modify any exisitng data

Comment: @uttamrao are you able to fix this?